# Hide an element when browser is zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible with CSS or JS to hide a  when the users zooms with his Browser? I do have a sticky Ad row which I want to hide once the user zooms with his browser. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Use max-width media rule

Comment: Yes it is possible.